# Hash table's key is messing up due to last input

Tags: c, hash, linked-list, hashtable, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to create a hash table program, that can input a hash key and a string data that will be stored in the hash table. Everything is fine except in "Menu == 2", everytime I try to search a string data by inputting its hash key, one (the last positioned) hash key in the table is changed to what I had inputted in "Menu == 2".

Here's the hash table from "Menu == 4" with `viewAll ()` function (after I input hash keys, and string datas through "Menu == 1"):

```
//FORMAT:
//[index]: [key] (string data) -> [key] (string data) -> ..

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//after I finished inputting all hash keys and string datas through menu 1  

[0]: 0 (INDIA) -> 97 (PAKISTAN) -> 194 (BURMA) -> 291 (AFGHANISTAN)
[1]: 1 (UNITED STATES) -> 98 (CANADA) -> 195 (MEXICO) -> 292 (PANAMA)
[2]: 2 (THE NETHERLANDS) -> 99 (LUXEMBOURG) -> 196 (BELGIUM) -> 293 (FRANCE)
[3]: 3 (SYRIA) -> 100 (LEBANON) -> 197 (ISRAEL) -> 294 (BAHRAIN)

//this hash table is correct

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

after menu 2 (last key inputted on menu 2 was 0)

[0]: 0 (INDIA) -> 97 (PAKISTAN) -> 194 (BURMA) -> 291 (AFGHANISTAN)
[1]: 1 (UNITED STATES) -> 98 (CANADA) -> 195 (MEXICO) -> 292 (PANAMA)
[2]: 2 (THE NETHERLANDS) -> 99 (LUXEMBOURG) -> 196 (BELGIUM) -> 293 (FRANCE)
[3]: 3 (SYRIA) -> 100 (LEBANON) -> 197 (ISRAEL) -> 0 (BAHRAIN)

//(why is BAHRAIN key 0, it should be 294)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

after menu 2 (last key inputted on menu 2 was 99)

[0]: 0 (INDIA) -> 97 (PAKISTAN) -> 194 (BURMA) -> 291 (AFGHANISTAN)
[1]: 1 (UNITED STATES) -> 98 (CANADA) -> 195 (MEXICO) -> 292 (PANAMA)
[2]: 2 (THE NETHERLANDS) -> 99 (LUXEMBOURG) -> 196 (BELGIUM) -> 293 (FRANCE)
[3]: 3 (SYRIA) -> 100 (LEBANON) -> 197 (ISRAEL) -> 99 (BAHRAIN)

//(why is BAHRAIN key 99, it should be 294)
```

As you can see, it's always the last positioned one to be changed by input menu 2.

Below is the source code, to not waste your time, I would look at the `void viewStrData ()` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct data {
    int key;
    char strData [100];
    struct data *next;
}*head [97], *tail [97], *node, *curr;

//index location within hash table = key % 97
int hashing (int key) {
    int result = key % 97;
    return result;
}

//input key and strData, push it to hash table
void push (int key, char strData [100]) {
    node = (struct data*) malloc(sizeof(struct data));
    node->key = key;
    strcpy (node->strData, strData);
    node->next = NULL;
    int idx = hashing (key);
    if (!head [idx]) {
        head [idx] = tail [idx] = node;
    } else {
        tail [idx]->next = node;
        tail [idx] = node;
    }
}

//see strData based on key 
void viewStrData (int key) {
    curr = head [hashing (key)];
    node->key = key;
    while (true) {
        if (curr->key == node->key) {
            printf ("[%s]\n", curr->strData);
            break;
        } else {
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }
}

//print out current hash table
void viewAll () {
    for (int i = 0; i < 97; i++) {
        printf ("[%d]: ", i);
        if (!head [i]) {
            printf ("-\n");
        } else {
            curr = head [i];
            while (curr) {
                if (curr == head [i]) {
                    printf ("%d", curr->key);
                    printf (" (%s)", curr->strData);
                } else {
                    printf (" -> %d", curr->key);
                    printf (" (%s)", curr->strData);
                }
                curr = curr->next;
            }
            printf ("\n");
        }
    }
}

int main () {

    int menu, key;
    char strData [100];

    while (true) {
        printf ("=======================================\n");
        printf ("MENU [1-3]: \n");
        printf ("1. INPUT DATA\n");
        printf ("2. SEARCH DATA\n");
        printf ("3. EXIT\n");
        printf ("=======================================\n");

        scanf ("%d", &menu);
        if (menu == 1) {
            printf ("ENTER KEY AND STRING DATA: \n");
            scanf ("%d %[^\n]", &key, strData);
            push (key, strData);
            printf ("HASH TABLE UPDATED!\n");
        } else if (menu == 2) {
            printf ("ENTER KEY TO FIND STRING DATA: \n");
            scanf ("%d", &key);
            printf ("STRING DATA OF KEY [%d] IS: ", key);
            viewStrData (key);
        } else if (menu == 3) {
            printf ("PROGRAM EXITED\n");
            break;
        } else if (menu = 4) {
            viewAll ();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way I could fix this? And sorry in advance that my code is sloppy and horrible to read.

Comment: `viewStrData` should not be making any changes to your data.  Do you see any statements in this function that are?

Comment: No, not that I can notice right away anyway. I figure it has something to do with a buffer input that lingers?

Comment: What do you think `node->key = key;` is doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because every time you call **push** you allocate new memory and store pointer to that memory in **node**:

```
    node = (struct data*) malloc(sizeof(struct data));
```

After that, this allocated data is inserted into the table, but the **node** still points to that data. And then when you run **viewStrData** you do **node->key = key**, and the **node** at this moment still points to the data that was last inserted when you called **push**. That's why every time you call **viewStrData**, last inserted node's key is updated to the received key.

I'd suggest to compare received key directly, like this:

```
void viewStrData (int key) {
curr = head [hashing (key)];
// node->key = key;   <-- No need for this
while (true) {
    if (curr->key == key) { // <-- compare key directly, instead of storing it into node->key
        printf ("[%s]\n", curr->strData);
        break;
    } else {
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}
```

P.S. There's a typo on this line:

```
        } else if (menu = 4) {
```

it should be **==** instead of **=**. Currently if menu is not 1, 2 or 3, it will **assign** 4 to it inside that if statement, and the result of 4 will be **true** every time. So even if you enter 7 there, menu will be overwritten by 4 and **viewAll** will be called.